# Black BG during render under tiles, looks fine in Tiled map editor

Tags: python, pygame, tiled

I started learning Pygame and Tiled map editor. I have the following test:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbez6.png)
It looks fine in the editor, the objects that have the black BG are currently on layer_4 (but they do it regardless of layer count).
I already tried using convert_alpha on it, ticking and unticking the transparency color in Tiled when loading in the tile map.

This is the original picture:
[Full picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNaXw.jpg)
This is the part where I load in the picture:

```
def import_cut_graphics(path):
surface = pygame.image.load(path).convert_alpha()
tile_num_x = int(surface.get_size()[0] / TILESIZE)
tile_num_y = int(surface.get_size()[1] / TILESIZE)

cut_tiles = []
for row in range(tile_num_y):
    for col in range(tile_num_x):
        x = col * TILESIZE
        y = row * TILESIZE
        new_surface = pygame.Surface((TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
        new_surface.blit(surface, (0, 0), pygame.Rect(x, y, TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
        cut_tiles.append(new_surface)

return cut_tiles
```

And this is where I work with it:

```
class Level:
def __init__(self, level_data, surface):
    # general setup
    self.all_layers = import_cut_graphics("img\ProjectUtumno_full.png")
    self.display_surface = surface
    self.world_shift = 0

    # terrain setup
    layer1_layout = import_csv_layout(level_data["layer_1"])
    self.layer1_sprites = self.create_tile_group(layer1_layout, 'layer_1')

    # grass setup
    layer2_layout = import_csv_layout(level_data["layer_2"])
    self.layer2_sprites = self.create_tile_group(layer2_layout, "layer_2")

    # crates
    layer3_layout = import_csv_layout(level_data["layer_3"])
    self.layer3_sprites = self.create_tile_group(layer3_layout, "layer_3")

    # layer 4
    layer4_layout = import_csv_layout(level_data["layer_4"])
    self.layer4_sprites = self.create_tile_group(layer4_layout, "layer_4")

def create_tile_group(self, layout, type):
    sprite_group = pygame.sprite.Group()

    for row_index, row in enumerate(layout):
        for col_index, val in enumerate(row):
            if val != '-1':
                x = col_index * TILESIZE
                y = row_index * TILESIZE

                if type == 'layer_1':
                    tile_surface = self.all_layers[int(val)]
                    sprite = StaticTile(TILESIZE, x, y, tile_surface)
                    sprite_group.add(sprite)

                if type == "layer_2" :
                    tile_surface = self.all_layers[int(val)]
                    sprite = StaticTile(TILESIZE, x, y, tile_surface)
                    sprite_group.add(sprite)

                if type == "layer_3" :
                    tile_surface = self.all_layers[int(val)]
                    sprite = StaticTile(TILESIZE, x, y, tile_surface)
                    sprite_group.add(sprite)

                if type == "layer_4" :
                    tile_surface = self.all_layers[int(val)]
                    sprite = StaticTile(TILESIZE, x, y, tile_surface)
                    sprite_group.add(sprite)

    return sprite_group

def run(self):
    # run the entire game / level
    self.camera()

    # layer1
    self.layer1_sprites.update(self.world_shift)
    self.layer1_sprites.draw(self.display_surface)

    # layer2
    self.layer2_sprites.update(self.world_shift)
    self.layer2_sprites.draw(self.display_surface)

    # layer3
    self.layer3_sprites.update(self.world_shift)
    self.layer3_sprites.draw(self.display_surface)

    # layer4
    self.layer4_sprites.update(self.world_shift)
    self.layer4_sprites.draw(self.display_surface)
```

This is my main game loop:

```
class Game:
def __init__(self):
    pygame.init()
    pygame.font.init()
    self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT))
    self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    self.screen_name = pygame.display.set_caption("New Game")
    self.running = True
    self.playing = False
    self.level = Level(level_0, self.screen)

    self.character_spritesheet = Spritesheet('img\MainCharacter\B_witch_idle.png')

def main(self):
    # game loop
    while self.running:
        self.events()
        self.update()
        self.draw()
    self.running = False

def draw(self):
    self.screen.fill(BLACK)
    self.level.run()
    self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)
    self.clock.tick(FPS)
    pygame.display.update()
```

I did try commenting the screen fill black and got the same result. I tried out set_colorkey with white/black colors but didn't work out.

I add my tile create class too:

```
class Tile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, size, x, y):
    super().__init__()
    self.image = pygame.Surface((size, size))
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(x, y))

def update(self, shift):
    self.rect.x += shift


class StaticTile(Tile):
def __init__(self, size, x, y, surface):
    super().__init__(size, x, y)
    self.image = surface
```

Thanks in advance if you can figure out why i have this problem.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone who's having this problem, I managed to solve it by this:
Inside my import_cut_graphics methode I added a set_colorkey(BLACK), turns out the problem occured when I was originally cutting the picture, therefore it didnt matter how much I change it at the latter phases since the problem was in an earlier stage.

```
def import_cut_graphics(path):
surface = pygame.image.load(path).convert_alpha()
tile_num_x = int(surface.get_size()[0] / TILESIZE)
tile_num_y = int(surface.get_size()[1] / TILESIZE)

cut_tiles = []
for row in range(tile_num_y):
    for col in range(tile_num_x):
        x = col * TILESIZE
        y = row * TILESIZE
        new_surface = pygame.Surface((TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
        new_surface.blit(surface, (0, 0), pygame.Rect(x, y, TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
        new_surface.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        cut_tiles.append(new_surface)

return cut_tiles
```